# Convert string replacement from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, replace, urlencode

We have an old VB.net application that is being rewritten in WPF and C#.
One of the functionalities in the application is to print barcodes and we have plenty of old printers that is using EPL.

Can someone please help to convert the line below to a C# equivalent.

```
Return Server.UrlEncode(value.Replace(Chr(13) & Chr(10), "_CRLF")
                             .Replace(Chr(34),"_QUOT")
                             .Replace(Chr(13), "_CR")
                             .Replace(Chr(10), "_LF")
                             .Replace(Chr(32), "_SPAC"))
```

Thank You

Comment: Those are just .NET calls. `String.Replace` works the same in VB.NET and C#? Do you understand what `Chr(13)` is? Or what `Chr()` does? Have you tried looking it up? There was no reason to use `Chr` in the original code anyway, one could use escape sequences like `\r`, `\n`, `\"` etc

Comment: value.Replace("\n", "_CRLF")
                             .Replace("","_QUOT")
                             .Replace("\r", "_CR")
                             .Replace("\f", "_LF")
                             .Replace(" ", "_SPAC")

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: VB doesn't have escape sequences, so exactly how would you do that in the original code, as you suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Hi also you can write it like this in C#:

```
Return Server.UrlEncode(value.Replace("\r\n", "_CRLF")
                             .Replace("\"","_QUOT")
                             .Replace("\r", "_CR")
                             .Replace("\n", "_LF")
                             .Replace(" ", "_SPAC"))
```

In your code Chr(number) number represent equivalent value for char in ascii table, and Chr() function return a string containing the character associated with the specified character code.

Look on ascii table Dec column http://www.asciitable.com.

Comment: This is wrong since in windows  a '\n' is 0x0D and 0x0A.

Comment: @jdweng no, `\n` is LF. You'd need to use `\r\n` to get a Windows-style newline. If you try `"\n".Length` in Linqpad you'd get `1`

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this.

```
       char[] spChs =  Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(new byte[]{ 13, 10, 34, 32});            
       string newString = value.Replace(spChs[0].ToString()+ spChs[1].ToString(), "_CRLF").Replace(spChs[2].ToString(), "_QUOT").Replace(spChs[0].ToString(), "_CR").Replace(spChs[1].ToString(), "_LF").Replace(spChs[3].ToString(), "_SPAC");
```

Comment: The two arrays make the code harder to read without offering any benefit